# ～ている + ～てしまう ordering

Tags: grammar

How do I combine the ～ている and ～てしまう verb conjugations together? Which of them should come first?

For example, I want to add ～てしまう conjugation to 間違えていた。Should this be 間違えていてしまった or 間違えてしまっていた? Or if they are both valid, do these have different meanings?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure they can sensibly be combined, even if the "rules" permit it. What exactly are you intending it to mean?

Comment: 間違えていてしまった would be understood as 間違えて（、そこに）いてしまった (I was there by mistake.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

間違えてしまっていた is the correct sentence. It's 間違っていた ("I had made a mistake" or "I was wrong") with a regrettable mood added. For this combination, (て)いた always refers to the continuation of the state. (て)しまう refers to something finished or irreversible, which naturally conflicts with the progressive sense of (て)いる.

I cannot explain why 間違えていてしまった is wrong, but we never say this (confirmed with BCCWJ).

Comment: Are there any words you can think of where the ～ていてしまった ordering would work? Or is it always the case that the ～(て)いる should be applied to the ～(て)しまう instead of vice-versa?

Comment: @octosquakk `verb + ないでいてしまう` (such as 見ないでいてしまう "to stay without seeing it") might be acceptable but this is still extremely rare according to [BCCWJ](https://shonagon.ninjal.ac.jp/).